# Wpf .Net Core 3 <PublishSingleFile> Builds but won't run

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core-3.0

I am working inside of a WPF application that I created using a preview version of VS 2019. This WPF app is running .net 3.0 and everything is fine and such. I can debug the application and everything works all nice. I publish it using the Publish util inside VS and I have the settings as such:

- Release
- netcoreapp3.0
- Self-Contained
- win-x64

I then added this to my .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This will compile and even builds a single executable which is awesome. The problem is when I click to run this new executable nothing happens, no errors, no windows, it just fails to launch.

**EDIT:**
I compiled it to a regular console window executable and I can now see an error. I have files that need to be copied into the directory like appsettings.json files. They are marked to be copied but because of the single file settings they aren't or are somehow being bundled with the exe.

Comment: Do you have a link to a repo that reproduces this behavior by any chance? Would like to see what is causing issues in the PublishSingleFile default output.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue